# un-expected results returned from insert into exec stored_procedure()

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm creating a temporary table with single nvarchar column. I have a stored procedure which returns a list of strings. I want to add one record at top and one at bottom along with data returned my stored procedure.

**Here is my sp code snippet:**

```
CREATE TABLE #tempData (col1 nvarchar(4000)) 
INSERT INTO #tempData values('SET IDENTITY_INSERT ['+@table_name+'] ON')
INSERT INTO #tempData EXEC (@Actual_Values)
INSERT INTO #tempData values('SET IDENTITY_INSERT ['+@table_name+'] OFF')
select * from #tempData
DROP TABLE #tempData
```

**Expected:**

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT ['+@table_name+'] ON
records returned from sp
SET IDENTITY_INSERT ['+@table_name+'] OFF
```

**returned:**

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT ['+@table_name+'] ON
some records returned from sp
SET IDENTITY_INSERT ['+@table_name+'] OFF
remainingrecords returned from sp
```

why all records from stored procedure are not in sequence. where am i interpreting wrong?.
please spare me with my questioning language and length.

Comment: Shouldn't you be expecting OFF not ON as the third value?

Comment: How exactly are you determining that they're "out of sequence"? If your #tempData table only has one column, and you just say "SELECT * FROM #tempData", do you expect the result to come back in the order the rows were inserted? This is not how SQL Server works - think of a table as a bag of unordered rows. If you want to be able to return the data in some form of an expected order, add an IDENTITY column, and order by that when you select.

Comment: why down vote. what's wrong in my question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no guarantee of order when selecting from a table. If you need the strings returned in order, you'll need to add an order column. You could try this:

```
CREATE TABLE #tempData (ID int IDENTITY(1,1), col1 nvarchar(4000))
INSERT INTO #tempData values('SET IDENTITY_INSERT ['+@table_name+'] ON')
INSERT INTO #tempData EXEC (@Actual_Values)
INSERT INTO #tempData values('SET IDENTITY_INSERT ['+@table_name+'] OFF')
select * from #tempData ORDER BY ID
DROP TABLE #tempData
```

Comment: got it. working fine after your suggestion. i didn't think of identity because for 4 tables (with 20-30 records) returning data as expected and for 2 tables (with more than 2000 records) returning un ordered. Thanks for your quick response.

Answer (score -1):

You can also try

```
select * from #tempData
ORDER BY CASE WHEN RIGHT(col1,2) = 'ON' THEN 0
              WHEN RIGHT(col1,3) = 'OFF' THEN 2
              ELSE 1 END
```

Assuming you Sp values do not end with `ON` or `OFF`

Comment: Unless OP is also concerned about the order of the statements between those two endpoints as well, in which case this isn't enough. I'm not sure whether or not that's the case.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But, my sp may return data ending with ON / OFF

Comment: Sure, you should go with Identity solution then. I have up-voted that answer first, just providing an additional idea.